# Classifying overlap in quantile ranges between rows

Tags: r

I have a dataset containing estimates for a change in slope between t and t-1, including the mean, q2.5 and q97.5 I want to find where changes in the slope are significant i.e. where the q2.5 and q97.5 values do not overlap between the current row and the row preceding it. Is there a simple way to do this in r?

A example dataset is provided here with the desired output below:

Example dataset

```
mean q2.5 q97.5
1   10    8    12
2   15   11    16
3   21   19    22
4   34   25    35
5   56   52    57
```

Desired output

```
  mean q2.5 q97.5 overlap
1   10    8    12      NA
2   15   11    16    TRUE
3   21   19    22   FALSE
4   34   25    35   FALSE
5   56   52    57   FALSE
```

Comment: can you provide the desired output for `head(example_dataset)`?

Comment: There is no t_1 in your dataset example

Comment: Hello both, I have uploaded a more simple example dataset and a desired output. I have also made it clearer in the question that t-1 is the row preceding a given row (t).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with `lag` from `dplyr` -

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate(overlap = q2.5 <= lag(q97.5) & q2.5 >= lag(q2.5))

#  mean q2.5 q97.5 overlap
#1   10    8    12      NA
#2   15   11    16    TRUE
#3   21   19    22   FALSE
#4   34   25    35   FALSE
#5   56   52    57   FALSE
```

Comment: Now, I am confused. If we change `df$q2.5[2] <- 1` the answer for second row should be `FALSE`, right? In which case, both of our answer fails and `mutate(overlap = q2.5 < lag(q97.5) & q2.5 > lag(q2.5))` works I think.